# SQLAlchemy Class is not mapped

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Im trying to update a user in FastAPI but i'm currently getting the error - `Class 'api.schemas.instructor.Instructor' is not mapped`

I've tried a couple of things to fix this like changing the schema and model but the results are either the error above or an error stating that the user already exists in the DB, is there anyway this can be resolved via the schema?

Heres my code;

Instructor schema

```
class Instructor(BaseModel):
    id: str
    full_name: str
    phone_number: int
    email: str
    is_active: bool
    is_superuser: bool
    sex: str
    car_type: str
    area_covered: str
    driving_school_name: str
    driving_school_description: Optional[str] = None
    adi_license: str
    profile_image_one: Optional[str] = None
    profile_image_two: Optional[str] = None
    profile_image_three: Optional[str] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Patch endpoint

```
@instructors.patch("/{user_id}")
def update(user_id: str, user: InstructorUpdate = Depends(InstructorUpdate.as_form), db: Session = Depends(d.get_db), profile_images: Optional[List[UploadFile]] = File(None)):
    current_user = Instructor(**jsonable_encoder(crd.get_user(db, user_id)))
    # current_user = jsonable_encoder(crd.get_user(db, user_id))
    if current_user:
        updated_user = crd.update_user(db, current_user, user, image_keys=image_keys)
        return updated_user
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="User not found")
```

Update user function

```
    def update_user(self, db: Session, db_obj: ModelType, usup: Any, image_keys: Optional[List[str]] = None):

        obj_data = db_obj

        if isinstance(usup, dict):
            update_data = usup
        else:
            update_data = usup.dict(exclude_unset=True)

        for field in obj_data:
            if field in update_data:
                if update_data[field] is not None:
                    setattr(db_obj, field, update_data[field])

        # Todo - Error here "Class 'api.schemas.instructor.Instructor' is not mapped", need to fix this
        db.add(db_obj)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_obj)
        return db_obj
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue, turned out that I casted my `db_obj` to Pydantic schema, that was the problem